# Pentaho PDI 5.3 Client Server Setup

Tags: shell, unix, installation, client-server, pentaho

I am setting up a new Pentaho DI 5.3 Installation. The Server is installed in Linux Box. Dev Team have Installed Pentaho Client Tools in Windows 7 Virtual Machine. Created Repository connecting to Server and all development are done in Repository.

This is the issue I am facing:- I have a File Location in UNIX Server /xxx/xxx where I will get and place all files from FTP Server. How do I connect to this Unix Location from Windows Client?

I tried reading the files using Text File Input giving the Unix Location directly and using Kettle Variables, But getting Error:- ****"Could not list the contents of "file:///C:/xxx/xxx" because it is not a folder."**** Does not recognize it as a Unix location.

I know I can use SSHGet and write a shell script, what are the other options that I have? && If I write a shell script, how will I give the location of script (if I am placing the script in UNIX Server /xxx/xxx).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the client tool on a different machine than where the DI Repository is located, you will not be able to browse the UNIX server's directory. You are, instead, developing in the context of Windows.

When working in a mixed environment like this, you would just type in the actual UNIX path in your input steps. Alternatively, you could use a kettle variable and specify the path in the server's kettle.properties file as well as a "temp development" path you can use on the Windows vm and specify it in that machine's kettle.properties file as well. That way one variable is used in your step, and you're not constantly editing the transformation between your dev and prod environments.